# connecting to SQLite with python 2.6, pandas and SqlAlhemy — mission impossibe?

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas, sqlalchemy, python-2.6

I am trying to deploy geospatial joint script on the cluster of machines at my school. Unfortunately, they have python 2.6 (standard for Cloudera), and I have to re-write my code accordingly.

Reading pandas.from_sql() requires SQLAlchemy connection to be established. However, the way they propose it does not work in python 2.6:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///%s' % path)

with engine.connect() as conn, conn.begin():
    chunks = pd.read_sql_table('tweets', conn, columns=columns, chunksize=50)
```

However, it seems that python 2.6 don't like 'with' statement, nor does it like 'with ... as ... , ... :'. So I had to modify the code slightly:

```
conn = engine.connect()
conn.begin()
chunks = pd.read_sql_table('tweets', conn, columns=columns, chunksize=50)
conn.close()
```

However, this throws me another error, pretty strange one:

```
 raise NotImplementedError("read_sql_table only supported for "
NotImplementedError: read_sql_table only supported for SQLAlchemy connectable.
```

How can I solve this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just nest the context managers like this:

```
with engine.connect() as conn:
    with conn.begin():
        chunks = ...
```

Syntax was added for multiple context managers in 2.7, true, but you could always work around it in 2.6.

Comment: good point, but it also prints "'Connection' object has no attribute '__exit__'", in this case, so I can't

Comment: @Casy_fill I think that means you're using a ridiculously old version of SQLAlchemy (i.e. <= 0.7.5). `Connection` objects have had an `__exit__` function since 0.7.6. Try upgrading your SQLAlchemy?